# Display data relevant to the user based on the favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

I feel Stack Overflow is a great place for any one interested in learning new things. But I feel there is a scope for improvement in the site.

One such case I feel that needs to be sorted out is, For example when I open the Stack Overflow page I see all the recent questions posted by Users across the site. Among those questions there would be several questions related to technology which I am unaware of at all.

So I feel that instead of displaying all the recent questions, filtering the questions based on the Logged in User's favourite tags would be great. So that User can actually see questions which he is aware of.

Hope to see this being implemented in Stack Overflow to be even more effective.

Comment: Filtering using favourites seems like a nice new idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**tag subscriptions**](https://stackexchange.com/filters/81844/my-filter) link in the homepage does the same. Just pass the tags which you want to get the update of and then save the filter.

[image]

- By clicking on tag subscriptions, you can create your own filter property to allow the tags.
- You can also select other websites tags
- all your favourite stackexchange sites posts will be available on single page.

For more information, go through this **[link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/)**.

PS: By using **ignored tags** option, you can ignore some of the tags on the website.

Comment: how many tags should i add to that ignore list. Lets say the user is a .net developer and to make sure that user can  see only .net related questions expecting the user to add all the other technology tags to ignore list would be awkward. Isn't it?

Comment: @sravan AFAIK,  .net is related to all tags like javascript, jquery, css, html, dojo, extjs, kendo, backbone, node, signalr and many more. If you want pure favourite tags then I am afraid you can't see anything on the page. You may like to check [tag subscriptions](http://stackexchange.com/filters/81844/my-filter) page instead.

Comment: I have specifed .net as just an example. What I wanted to point out was that lets say i am a dot net user and i don't want some thing like java , or android or php to be on my home screen.it was jsut an example to let you undersand what i wanted to tel you.

Comment: @sravan that's what `tag subscription` link does. Did you check it??

Comment: @Sravan I updated my post.